# GitHub not letting me turn on branch protection status checks for develop branch on my repo, but status checks are working

Tags: github

I am administering this repo: https://github.com/NOAA-EMC/NCEPLIBS-w3nco

I have a .github/workflows yml file, and it is working, and when I make a PR against develop branch, the tests run, and I get the little green checkmark telling me that it worked:

[image]

Yet when I try to require status checks in develop branch protection, there is no check-box to do it:

[image]

How do I get GitHub to find the status checks that are running on this code?

Comment: I think the check needs to be run one week before enabling the requirement at maximum.